# How can I re-create EF 4.1 EDMX models for EF 6 in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am testing to migrate to EntityFramework 6 from 4.1.

I have some .EDMX models created by designer in VS 2010.

Question is: How can I re-create those EDMX models for EF 6? as I read that VS 2010 designer is not supporting EF .

Any advise?*emphasized text*

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to re-create the EDMX models.  You should be able to right click in the EDMX designer, then hit 'Add Code Generation Item'.  In the 'Add New Item' box, click 'Online Templates' and search for 'EF 5.x DbContext Generator'.  That'll add a tt file which can generate your POCO objects.  I couldn't find an EF 6 generator for VS2010 but we've had success using the EF5 generator with the EF6 framework.  After all, they're just POCOs.